# Java + Android + Eclipse. attempt to test on real device fails: can't find Activity

Tags: java, android, eclipse

This is a simple application with one Activity class used to display a SVG with pinch possibilities. It has already been tested on a real device (NEXUS 4). On Friday. Minor changests did not affect neither ths main class not manifest.

Now I spent hours obtaining: ClassNotFoundException
I checked the result APK as well as the DEX files - this class is included.

Any suggestions and hints will be appreciated.

```
08-04 16:10:52.957: E/AndroidRuntime(352): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.svgdisplaypinchtest/com.example.svgdisplaypinchtest.SVGDisplayPinchActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.svgdisplaypinchtest.SVGDisplayPinchActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.svgdisplaypinchtest-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.example.svgdisplaypinchtest-1, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
08-04 16:10:52.957: E/AndroidRuntime(352):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2110)
08-04 16:10:52.957: E/AndroidRuntime(352):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233)
08-04 16:10:52.957: E/AndroidRuntime(352):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
08-04 16:10:52.957: E/AndroidRuntime(352):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
08-04 16:10:52.957: E/AndroidRuntime(352):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
08-04 16:10:52.957: E/AndroidRuntime(352):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
08-04 16:10:52.957: E/AndroidRuntime(352):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
08-04 16:10:52.957: E/AndroidRuntime(352):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-04 16:10:52.957: E/AndroidRuntime(352):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
08-04 16:10:52.957: E/AndroidRuntime(352):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
08-04 16:10:52.957: E/AndroidRuntime(352):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
08-04 16:10:52.957: E/AndroidRuntime(352):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-04 16:10:52.957: E/AndroidRuntime(352): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.svgdisplaypinchtest.SVGDisplayPinchActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.svgdisplaypinchtest-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.example.svgdisplaypinchtest-1, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
08-04 16:10:52.957: E/AndroidRuntime(352):  at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
08-04 16:10:52.957: E/AndroidRuntime(352):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497)
08-04 16:10:52.957: E/AndroidRuntime(352):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)
08-04 16:10:52.957: E/AndroidRuntime(352):  at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1061)
08-04 16:10:52.957: E/AndroidRuntime(352):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2101)
08-04 16:10:52.957: E/AndroidRuntime(352):  ... 11 more
```

EDIT: thanks for your question about manifest. as concerns clean and rebuild etc. I did it so many times ...
Here is the manifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.svgdisplaypinchtest"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="11"
    android:targetSdkVersion="20" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".SVGDisplayPinchActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: Please show us your manifest, and also try to clean and rebuild.

Comment: use `com.example.svgdisplaypinchtest.SVGDisplayPinchActivity` in `android:name` after that clean your project and run

Answer (score 1):

Problem was solved with a rude-force method.

- just copy all filess to a safe folder.
- delete the project from Eclipse (with files !).
- import them back as project (from aforesaid 'safe folder').

Answer (score 0):

Open `SVGDisplayPinchActivity` and check on top what is the package name. It is not necessary that it will be `com.example.svgdisplaypinchtest`. It can be `com.example.ui` or so.

Copy that and use that complete package name in your manifest. eg.

```
<activity
    android:name="com.example.ui.SVGDisplayPinchActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
```

Comment: package com.example.svgdisplaypinchtest;

Comment: I wish to add that the example application was working fine on Friday. there were no changes in manifest or the activity class code. minor changes related to res/values/styles.